# is there any way to count by values in a column and find a specific value from another column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine two tables,

one(Post Table) is for posts and the other one(Like Table) is for likes that people put on the posts.
then I want to render 10 posts with the number of likes that the posts got and I want to mark on each post if the user put a like on it before or not.

I managed to select counts group by post_id on the Like Table so I know how many likes each post has

but I can't think of any way to do that and make the user see if the user put a like on the posts before at the same time.

so what I came up with is:

1. somehow count the user's id(from Like Table) and from the result of the group by post_id and join two results
2. just use two mysql queries

I don't know how to do any of them. I would like to know about more detailed way to do those if they're possible to do or other way to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is probably the simplest way to do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT postID, COUNT(*) likes, COUNT(CASE WHEN userID = 123 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) usersLikes 
FROM Likes 
GROUP BY postID
) l ON l.postID = p.id
```